# Full Text Search in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for tutorials to implement a full text search method in postgresql. 
I have tried several examples but no one performing.
I tried indexing GIN, GIST, and several research method, but search times is too high.
I have a datadase with more than 4M records containing names of artists. 
I need to develop a search method that includes fuzzystrseach algorithms.

Comment: Have you looked at an `explain analyze` of your query and verified that the index is actually used? Can you post the explain analyze and the table and index definition?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but I would suggest you to try Solr, Sphinx or some other search server. Solr will handle 4M rows and fuzzy search without problems. I have struggled with the same problem before and my solution was to use Solr. I couldn't get good enough performance by using database.

Solr can do much more than just fuzzy search. Solr can preprocess text with stemmer to improve search results even without fuzzy search. Stemming gives better performance than fuzzy search because it is done when indexing and the actual search can be performed as exact match.

With Solr you can create index straight from the database so you don't have to write any additional piece of software to feed the data into Solr. I don't have experience of other search servers so I can't say if they have similar abilities.

Comment: Postgres can do stemming as well. But basically I do agree with you. Full text search is better left to a specialized system.